# Calculating Phase of Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-transform

im trying to understand how to calcuate  a Phase of a function in the frequency domain.

from what i know, to calculating a phase i need to use this formula :

```
arctan(Im/Re)
```

now im trying to calculate the phase of this func:

```
f(w) = e^(-jwT/2)*sinc(w/Ws)
```

this is FT of shifted Rectangle func.

now from what i see there is no Real part in this func so how do i calculate the phase?

the phase graph of this function is looks like f(w) = -w.

i hope it was clear, thanks!

Comment: It's $-\omega\frac{T}{2}$

Comment: The phase for $e^{j\phi}$ which is known as phase function, is precisely $\phi$

Comment: thanks alot!!!!